# Android In-App Billing (Subscription) exemptions?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription

I'm planning on adding in-app billing subscriptions to my android app. Sort of adding a feature to go premium with additional features. I have been reading this [article](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html) to learn more about this. I understand that there are certain intervals to choose from ie. weekly, monthly etc.

However, my concern is that there are some users that I want to be exempted from this subscription. I want them to be premium users without having to pay me anything (me, family and friends). Is there a way I can do this using the Google Play Console or thru In-App Billing Api?

Answer (score 0):

You may use alpha/beta release channel (in parallel with production channel) and add your relatives and friends emails as testers, so they can buy any products or subscriptions without fees.

Comment: Thanks. I will consider this approach. However, I would still like to hear some more suggestions maybe from others.